# my Europcar shares are gone !! France

Tags: shares, capital-loss, share-repurchase

France Boursorama

I checked my bank account today and I noticed that all my Europcar shares are gone.
I heard that Europcar will be purchased by VOLKSWAGEN GROUP.

I received some letters from my bank asking me to choose one for 3 options and send them back the letter. it was a bit complicated letter with symbols, so I just ignored them.

does that mean that I just lost everything once VOLKSWAGEN bought Europcar?
it's that simple ? :::

Comment: Probably easiest to follow up with the bank, but I doubt the asset would be forfeit even with your inaction.

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.reuters.com/markets/deals/volkswagen-led-consortium-obtains-8738-europcar-shares-takeover-bid-2022-06-15/) at least one of the 3 options was to join the sale and get bought out by VW. You'll need to check with your bank what their default was in case of your inaction.

Comment: Banks do not just steal your money. They have certainly done *something* with your shares, even if you didn't fill out the form. You could ask the bank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Europcar was acquired through a tender offer and then through a squeeze-out. The purchase price per share was 0.50 euros with a bonus of 0.01 euros to those who tendered their shares.

Because you are being squeezed out, your shares will be sold at the purchase price; but because you did not tender them, you will not receive the bonus.

https://europcar-mobility-group.com/press-releases

Comment: well, finally my shares were automatically sold, I just got my cash today